# Android - Multiple EditText in single TableRow

Tags: android, android-edittext, tablerow

I have two EditText controls in one TableLayout>TableRow. I have another TableLayout>TableRow that has a single EditText control. When I hit "Enter" or "Next" from the first EditText field, the focus goes to the next table/row instead of the EditText field in the same TableRow. I've searched, but haven't had any luck finding an answer to this. How can I make the focus go to the next EditText field, instead of the EditText field in the next table?

```
            <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

              <TableRow 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView 
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:text="State" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="2sp" 
                        android:layout_marginRight="47dp" 
                        android:padding="3dp" 
                        android:textColor="@color/white" 
                        android:textStyle="normal" 
                        android:textSize="12dp">
                    </TextView>

                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_height="30sp" 
                        android:id="@+id/addeditServeeDetail_StateTextBox" 
                        android:layout_width="50dp" 
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="10sp" 
                        android:maxLength="2" android:imeOptions="actionNext">
                    </EditText>

                    <TextView 
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:text="Zip" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="2sp" 
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"  
                        android:padding="3dp" 
                        android:textColor="@color/white" 
                        android:textStyle="normal" 
                        android:textSize="12dp">
                    </TextView>

                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_height="30sp" 
                        android:id="@+id/addeditServeeDetail_ZipTextBox" 
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="10sp" 
                        android:maxLength="10">
                    </EditText>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

              <TableRow 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp">

                <TextView 
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:text="County" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="2sp" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp" 
                    android:padding="3dp" 
                    android:textColor="@color/white" 
                    android:textStyle="normal" 
                    android:textSize="12dp">
                </TextView>

                <EditText 
                    android:layout_height="30sp" 
                    android:id="@+id/addeditServeeDetail_CountyTextBox" 
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" 
                    android:textSize="10sp">
                </EditText>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the focus to move from item to item in an exact order you need to specify that in the layout file.

See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/YourNextEditText"
```

Answer (score -1):

do it manually...:P

place an event which triggers when first edittext loses focus, in that event set focus to second edittext by using edittext.requestFocus() function.

use this event for focus in/out:
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener();